Need help F-statistics requirment
I was working on the thesis and was stuck in the F test, I used a probability value of 0.05 or 5% before but my test results were not enough or exceeded the conditions. Now I want to try using a probability value of 0.1 or 10% for the conditions to be met.
My question is, is there a basis or reference for us to use the probability value of 10%, does that probability value have to be 5%? If you have any references please help, thank you
Right now im using panel model on eviews 10

I believe Fisher, the father of statistics, suggested the 5% level as a measure of significance, and today it is widely accepted as a standard. But it is an arbitrary cutoff essentially. Some fields may use 10% and other fields use 1% as the cutoff.

"I used a probability value of 0.05 or 5% before but my test results were not enough or exceeded the conditions. Now I want to try using a probability value of 0.1" - Having already discussed this elsewhere (where the question was then deleted), I hesitate to try to address it at length here, so I will just note that changing the level $⍺$ in the face of a non-rejection causes you to mislead people about the actual previous type I error rate (and in turn you would mislead them about what your p-values mean). It might help if you clarify the situation you're in / why you need to change $⍺$.

The use of the 5% significance level ($\alpha=.05$) is generally attributed to Ronald Fisher.

It is convenient to take this point as a limit in judging whether a deviation is to be considered significant or not. Deviations exceeding twice the standard deviation are thus formally regarded as significant. Source

It is also generally accepted that this level is somehow arbitrary. Fisher himself felt that other significance levels could be used.

If one in twenty does not seem high enough odds, we may, if we
prefer it, draw the line at one in fifty or one in a hundred. Personally, the writer prefers to set a low standard of significance at the 5 per cent point, and ignore entirely all results which fails to reach this level. A scientific fact should be regarded as experimentally established only if a properly designed experiment rarely fails to give this level of significance. Source

But you may find the following article quite interesting, which actually shows that such a "threshold of significance" predates Fisher, and that its value ($\approx 5$%) also predates Fisher, and was not that arbitrary after all.
So, if you wanted to use a .1 level of significance, you certainly could. But ... you should have decided to do so before you collected the data, and not after you analyzed your results, and obtained a p-value somewhere between .05 and .1. This is considered data dredging, and is poor statistical practice as it can lead to false positives inflation.
So if an astute reader (or supervisor) sees your p-value at (e.g.) .07, and reads your conclusion that the result is significant at the .1 level, they would immediately question your choice of this .1 significance level. You will have to defend why you picked a level different from the "generally accepted" .05.
Now, to be clear, I have used significance of .1, and even .2 many times, and for data which went to regulatory agencies for approval. But this was predeterminated before data collection, and we had valid reasons why a higher false positive risk was acceptable. That does not seem to be your case.
